# Grafana's panels' horizontal axes alignment

Tags: grafana

How to align Grafana's panels' horizontal axes?

There are several time-series panels on a Grafana dashboard. The panels horizontal axes (X-axes) are the same, i.e. time. Different panels show different variables of different units on Y-axes, some panels consist of two Y-axes. When the time range is chosen, due to existing right axis and variable unit panels' horizontal axes ticks are not aligned vertically.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible. But maybe Shared crosshair or Shared tooltip might mitigates this for you.